# Python up arrow in txt file when i have written to it with f.write

Tags: python, text

Alright so I have used

```
f.write("%s,%s \n %s,%s\n" % (textb, timesec, textr, timesec))
```

and when I open up my text file I see
38.6
,1342.0
43.71
,1342.0
38.6
,1344.0
43.71
but here is the kicker there is a unicode emoji (of an up arrow) right before that comma, idk why, I never told it to \n there and I would like to get rid of it so I can graph the data later.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

fixed, did a [:-2]
so yeah super easy fix lul